# No se muestra el Alert

Tags: javascript

No entiendo porque no se muestra el alert

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<input type = "text" id = "texto" ></imput><br>
<input type = "button"  value = "boton" onclick = "validar()"></imput>
</body>
</html>

<script>
function validar(){
    var str = document.getElementById("texto").value;
}
alert(str);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente se este mostrando cuando se carga la pagina, pero como la variable `str` no esta definida de forma global se genera un error de javascript.

Si accedes al developer tools del browser, con la tecla F12, podrias analizar la solapa `Console` alli veras el error de javascript que menciono.

Lo que veo es que si el `alert` debe mostrarse cuando se presiona el boton el alert deba estar dentro de la funcion

```js
function validar(){
  var str = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<input type = "text" id = "texto" ></imput><br>
<input type = "button"  value = "boton" onclick = "validar()"></imput>
</body>
</html>
```